# How to set a Greenplum datasource in IBM Liberty Server

Tags: postgresql, websphere, websphere-liberty, greenplum

I have an IBM WebSphere Liberty server and a Greenplum Database. I want liberty server to connect Greenplum with SSL.

Here is my setting in server.xml:

```
<dataSource id="GreenplumDataSource" jndiName="jdbc/greenplum" type="javax.sql.DataSource">
    <jdbcDriver libraryRef="GreenplumLib" javax.sql.DataSource="com.pivotal.jdbcx.GreenplumDataSource"/>
    <properties databaseName="postgres" serverName="10.x.x.1" portNumber="5432" user="x" password="x" URL="jdbc:pivotal:greenplum://10.x.x.1:5432;DatabaseName=postgres;EncryptionMethod=SSL;CryptoProtocolVersion=TLSv1.2;ValidateServerCertificate=false"/> 
</dataSource>
<library id="GreenplumLib">
    <file name="/data/IBM/WebSphere/Liberty/usr/lib/PROGRESS_DATADIRECT_JDBC_DRIVER_PIVOTAL_GREENPLUM_5.1.4.000275.jar"/>
</library>
```

A simple application uses this JNDI to connect Greenplum. And I get an error from the application:

**Try to get connection : = jdbc/greenplum !!! Did not get the connection = java.sql.SQLInvalidAuthorizationSpecException: [Pivotal][Greenplum JDBC Driver][Greenplum]no pg_hba.conf entry for host "10.161.113.15", user "gpadmin", database "postgres", SSL off. DSRA0010E: SQL State = 28000, Error Code = 0**

It seems the data source does not use SSL to connect Greenplum. Is there something wrong with my settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your reply. I have fixed the issue. I set the wrong data source type and driver class before. Here is the correct setting:

```
<dataSource id="GreenplumDataSource" jndiName="jdbc/greenplum" type="java.sql.Driver">
    <jdbcDriver libraryRef="GreenplumLib" javax.sql.DataSource="com.pivotal.jdbc.GreenplumDriver"/>
    <properties databaseName="postgres" serverName="10.x.x.1" portNumber="5432" user="x" password="x" URL="jdbc:pivotal:greenplum://10.x.x.1:5432;DatabaseName=postgres;EncryptionMethod=SSL;CryptoProtocolVersion=TLSv1.2;ValidateServerCertificate=false"/>
</dataSource>
```

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://docs.progress.com/bundle/datadirect-connect-jdbc-51/page/Connection-Properties_2.html) for the properties supported by this driver does not indicate that its DataSource has a URL property, so I suspect that everything you put under the URL attribute is being ignored.

Try specifying each of the properties individually, as follows,

```
<dataSource id="GreenplumDataSource" jndiName="jdbc/greenplum" type="javax.sql.DataSource">
    <jdbcDriver libraryRef="GreenplumLib" javax.sql.DataSource="com.pivotal.jdbcx.GreenplumDataSource"/>
    <properties databaseName="postgres" serverName="10.x.x.1" portNumber="5432" user="x" password="x" encryptionMethod="SSL" cryptoProtocolVersion="TLSv1.2" validateServerCertificate="false"/>
</dataSource>
```

Hopefully this will work. The JDBC driver's documentation isn't very clear on whether the listed properties all pertain to their DataSource, or DriverManager, or both.  If you end up needing to have Liberty connect via the DriverManager instead, you can configure it to do that in recent versions, but let's try the DataSource approach first and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the issue is that the pg_hba.conf file for Greenplum has not been edited to allow this host to connect (though there may be issues with the connection string as listed above). You should add a line to pg_hba.con in Greenplum's $MASTER_DATA_DIRECTORY something like:

host all gpadmin 10.161.113.0/24 md5

That would set up connectivity on all databases for gpadmin connecting on the 10.161.113 subnet.  After editing the file, run gpstop -u to update the configuration across the cluster.

As a practical note, this is trying to connect to the postgres database.  That is not a good idea as that manages (I believe) the system catalog database.  You should create a separate database and try to connect to that instead.
Jim